# Query to get hierarchy from a table in Sybase

Tags: sql, sybase, hierarchy

I have a table with following structure:

> ```
> Emp Rel_Emp relation
> A   B       1
> A   C       1
> B   D       1
> B   A       0
> ....
> ```

In above table if "Rel_Emp" is child then relation is "1" if its parent then relation is "0".  I need to write a query to get the parent child hierarchy [There can be multiple trees in table].

I know how to achieve this in oracle [by using "connect by prior" clause] but i need to do this in sybase.
Can someone please guide me.

P.S: I have always worked in oracle and dont have much idea about sybase

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Self-Join** here.

Self Join is the act of joining one table with itself.

> Self Join is often very useful to convert a hierarchical structure
>   into a flat structure

```
SELECT e.name EMPLOYEE, m.name MANAGER
FROM EMPLOYEE e, EMPLOYEE m
WHERE e.mgr_id = m.id (+)
```

For more [info](http://www.dwbiconcepts.com/tutorial/24-interview-questions/190-top-20-sql-interview-questions-with-answers.html).